# How useful is it to make a global function fire a larger local function?

Tags: function, lua, roblox

So, this is the thing. In my local script, i've got a global function which recognizes when the user is holding down a key and sets to true a boolean that fires a local function, which is VERY large.

The local function in question:

```
local function pegarunbalazo()
    if cargador ~= 0 and not waza and not alhombro then

    -- 78 lines of code, of which some define variables, later...
    
    task.wait (0.1) 

end
```

The global function in question:

```
    conn = UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, gameProcessedEvent)
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
            if debounce then return end

            debounce=true
            triggering = true

            while triggering do
                pegarunbalazo()
                
            end
            
            debounce=false
            
        end
            
    end)
```

How useful is this? does it reduce the memory used? does it make it less eficcent? would it be the same to place the code inside of the local function directly into the global one?

Any kind of help, suggestion, or fix provided will be aprecciated and taken into account.

Comment: Memory usage and efficiency are the same (with and without local function).  But readability of the code is different.

Comment: @ESkri absolutely the same? like, no slight performance boost in one compared to the other?

Comment: In both cases it runs the exact same code with slightly different memory locations, the call overhead is neglectable. If the function is large, I would even try to further pull out common parts. But 70 lines still seems reasonable.
If you are interested, you can check what's happening under the hood using e.g., https://www.luac.nl/